Looking for q-analog of derangement anagrams for a word
I have already known QPermutationDerangement:
It describes the distribution
$$
d_n(q)=\sum_{\sigma \in D_n} q^{\operatorname{maj}(\sigma)}
$$
Where we sum over all derangements of an $n$ element set.
I'd like to use the formula:
$$
d_n(q)=[n]!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{[k]!} q^{\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)} 
$$
Clear["Global`*"];

DescentSet[p_] := Table[
  If[p[[i]] > p[[i + 1]], i, Sequence @@ {}], 
  {i, Length[p] - 1}
];

MajorIndex[p_] := Total@DescentSet[p];

(* Generalization of the number of derangements *)
QPermutationDerangement[n_, q_] := 
  QFactorial[n, q] * 
  Sum[(-1)^k * q^Binomial[k, 2] / QFactorial[k, q], {k, 0, n}]

n = 6;

(* q-analog of permutation derangements *)
QPermutationDerangement[n, q] // FullSimplify // FunctionExpand // 
   CoefficientList[#, q] & // Sort // Print

Map[MajorIndex, Derangements[Range[n]]] // Tally // 
  Map[#[[All, 2]] &, #] & // Sort


I have already known the number of derangement anagrams for a word with character counts $\{ n_1,n_2, \cdots, n_k \}$ is
$$
\int_0^{\infty } \exp (-x) \prod\limits_{i} \left[(-1)^{n_i} L_{n_i}(x)\right] \, \mathrm{d} x
$$
DerangementsCount[nvec_List] := 
  Integrate[
    Exp[-x] Apply[Times, (-1)^nvec LaguerreL[nvec, x]], 
    {x, 0, Infinity}
  ]

chars = Characters["Mathematica"] // ToLowerCase

DerangementsCount[Tally[chars][[All, 2]]]

Count[Permutations[chars],  x_ /; Inner[UnsameQ, x, chars, And]]


Reference request:
Looking for q-analog of derangement anagrams for a word.

ON LINEARIZATION COEFFICIENTS OF q-LAGUERRE POLYNOMIALS
may help.

This is an interesting question, albeit a bit poorly presented. How do you define anagrams for words? I can think of at least two different definitions...

All images of the multiset of letters under the derangements. 2. All lists of letters in the word, where no letter agrees with the letter in the original word.

In both cases, you can also define a q-analog via major index, which would agree with the q-multinomial coefficient definition.

To make the first sentence of @PerAlexandersson's comment more concrete: Please make your question understandable for people that do not use Mathematica; in fact, please do not use any Mma code at all. This might help your question(s) to get a little more attention.


Use $\textbf{Theorem 1.1}$ from [1],
The linearization coefficients of q-Laguerre polynomials are given by
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(L_{n_1}(x ; q, y) \cdots L_{n_k}(x ; q, y)\right)=\sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal{D}\left(n_1, \ldots, n_k\right)} y^{\operatorname{wex}(\sigma)} q^{\operatorname{cross}(\sigma)}
$$
The below code is correct.
for case $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)=(1,2,3) \scriptstyle{\quad\text{or permutations of (1,2,3)}}$
$$
\text{LHS}=y^3 q^6+4 y^3 q^5+8 y^3 q^4+10 y^3 q^3+8 y^3 q^2+4 y^3 q+y^3=\text{RHS}
$$
for case $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)=(2,3,4) \scriptstyle{\quad\text{or permutations of (2,3,4)}}$
$$
\text{LHS}=y^5 q^{16}+8 y^5 q^{15}+y^4 q^{15}+33 y^5 q^{14}+8 y^4 q^{14}+93 y^5 q^{13}+33 y^4 q^{13}+199 y^5 q^{12}+93 y^4 q^{12}+341 y^5 q^{11}+199 y^4 q^{11}+482 y^5 q^{10}+341 y^4 q^{10}+571 y^5 q^9+482 y^4 q^9+571 y^5 q^8+571 y^4 q^8+482 y^5 q^7+571 y^4 q^7+341 y^5 q^6+482 y^4 q^6+199 y^5 q^5+341 y^4 q^5+93 y^5 q^4+199 y^4 q^4+33 y^5 q^3+93 y^4 q^3+8 y^5 q^2+33 y^4 q^2+y^5 q+8 y^4 q+y^4
=\text{RHS}
$$

Clear["Global`*"];
nkVec = {1, 2, 3};
n = Total[nkVec];
k = Length[nkVec];
chars = Permutations[Range[n]];

judgeFunc[perm_] := 
  Module[{nSums, i, j}, nSums = Prepend[Accumulate[nkVec], 0];(*n_0=0,
   cumulative sums*)
   For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
    For[j = 1, j <= k, j++, 
      If[nSums[[j]] + 1 <= i <= nSums[[j + 1]] && 
         nSums[[j]] + 1 <= perm[[i]] <= nSums[[j + 1]], 
        Return[False]];];];
   True];

derangements = Select[chars, judgeFunc];
wex[p_] := With[{n = Length@p}, Sum[Boole[p[[i]] >= i], {i, 1, n}]];
ov[p_] := 
  With[{n = Length@p}, 
   Sum[Boole@
     Or[i < j <= p[[i]] < p[[j]], p[[j]] < p[[i]] < j < i], {i, 1, 
     n}, {j, 1, n}]];
cross[p_] := ov[p];
rhs = Sum[y^wex[\[Sigma]]*q^cross[\[Sigma]], {\[Sigma], derangements}];
Print["rhs=", rhs];

QInteger[n_Integer, q_ : 1] := QBinomial[n, 1, q];
OrderedForm[x_] := 
  HoldForm[+##] & @@ (x^#1[[1]] #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[#, x]) &;

QYLaguerreLExplicitFormula[n_, x_, {q_, y_}] := 
  Sum[(-1)^(n - k)*QFactorial[n, q]/QFactorial[k, q]*
    QBinomial[n, k, q]*q^(k*(k - n))*y^(n - k)*
    Product[(x - (1 - y*q^(-j))*QInteger[j, q]), {j, 0, k - 1}], {k, 
    0, n}];

QYLaguerreL[0, x, {q_, y_}] := 1;
QYLaguerreL[1, x, {q_, y_}] := x - y;
QYLaguerreL[2, x, {q_, y_}] := x^2 - (y*q + 2 y + 1) x + y^2 + y^2*q;
QYLaguerreL[n_, 
   x_, {q_, y_}] := (x - y*QInteger[n, q] - QInteger[n - 1, q])*
    QYLaguerreL[n - 1, x, {q, y}] - 
   y*QInteger[n - 1, q]^2*QYLaguerreL[n - 2, x, {q, y}];

Print["QYLaguerreL[3,x,{q,y}]=", 
  QYLaguerreL[3, x, {q, y}] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify // 
    Expand // OrderedForm[x]];

Print["QYLaguerreLExplicitFormula[3,x,{q,y}]=", 
  QYLaguerreLExplicitFormula[3, x, {q, y}] // FunctionExpand // 
     FullSimplify // Expand // OrderedForm[x]];


productOfQYLaguerreL = 
  Product[QYLaguerreL[nk, x, {q, y}], {nk, nkVec}] // FunctionExpand //
     FullSimplify // Expand;

Print["productOfQYLaguerreL=", productOfQYLaguerreL // OrderedForm[x]];


mathcalL[n_] := 
  mathcalL[n] = Sum[y^wex[p]*q^cross[p], {p, Permutations[Range[n]]}];
Print["test mathcalL for n=0..=6 at {y->1,q->1}  ", 
  mathcalL /@ Range[0, 6] /. {y -> 1, q -> 1}];
lhs = Module[{coeffs = CoefficientList[productOfQYLaguerreL, x]}, 
   Sum[coeffs[[i]]*mathcalL[i - 1], {i, 1, Length@coeffs}] // 
       FullSimplify // Expand // FullSimplify // Expand];
Print["lhs=", lhs];
Print["lhs==rhs  ", lhs == rhs];

chars = Apply[Join, 
   Table[ConstantArray[i, nkVec[[i]]], {i, Length@nkVec}]];
Print["chars=", chars];
Print["Derangements of word, then do permutation for each type of \
element in every derangment. Count=", 
  Count[Permutations[chars], x_ /; Inner[UnsameQ, x, chars, And]]*
   Product[nk!, {nk, nkVec}]];
Print["Permutations of [n], then select valid permutations as \
derangments. Count=", derangements // Length];
Print["rhs/.{q->1,y->1} = ", rhs /. {q -> 1, y -> 1}];
Print["lhs/.{q->1,y->1} = ", lhs /. {q -> 1, y -> 1}];

[1] ON LINEARIZATION COEFFICIENTS OF q-LAGUERRE POLYNOMIALS
